# How to exclude folder from stream temporarily then include it later on

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I want to download a stream to a workspace and exclude certain folder(because it's too large)
then when I am done downloading I want to download it to my workspace

so

1- how to exclude a folder from stream

2- how to include the same folder without messing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to exclude it from your initial sync operation, you don't necessarily need to modify the stream at all.  (Modifying the stream may potentially impact other workspaces using the same stream, which you don't want.)

Edit your client to point at the new stream (in this instance you don't want to use `p4 switch` since that auto-syncs the new stream), and then sync only the folders that you need (i.e. enumerate all the top-level folders *except* for the big folder in your `sync` command).

The next time you do an unrestricted sync, it will pick up everything that hasn't been downloaded, including the big folder that you avoided the first time around.

Comment: I am using the Helix visual client, is there a similar way to do that in the client, sorry i forgot to mention that?

Comment: I *think* P4V gives you the option to sync the new stream (checked by default) when you switch streams.  Uncheck it, and then manually sync the other folders by selecting them (excluding the one you don't want) and doing "get latest".  If P4V auto-syncs you anyway, you can always cancel the sync and then manually sync the stuff you want anyway.